# Very slow wifi with intel network adapter on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I wanted to try out Linux on my laptop so I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I dual boot with windows 10. However I have had issues with wifi from the start. I have been trying for about a week to fix the problem now, and so far nothing has worked. My wifi shows that it is connected and I can access the internet, however loading websites is very slow. When I run a speedtest, my speed is very high but then the speedtest hangs and crashes halfway.

Another thing is that this issue also makes my mouse and keyboard input lag. After looking on the internet I found that: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` followed by `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` does make the connection more stable but it maxes my speed at 20 MBps. I already tried updating to a newer kernel (5.7.3) with no succes.

I really hope that someone can help me with this problem as I am very new to linux and am not sure how to find the problem myself.

Network adapter: Intel Wireless AC 9560
`dmesg | grep iwl`:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cT38pZpnBV/
`sudo dkms status`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NRpkgB96kw/

Comment: Please do: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. Also, let us see a new paste of `dmesg | grep iwl`after the reboot. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, no improvement. Seems like I'm still getting the same errors. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yHkvsNrkVq/

Comment: Does `11n_disable=8` help? Do the same errors appear? `dmesg | grep Microcode`